# Spring Integration validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-integration

What is the best way to do validation in Spring Integration.
For example if we have an inbound gateway, when a message is received we want to validate it. If it's not valid -> return the validation errors to the gateway, else -> proceed with the normal flow of the application(transform, handle ...).

I tried a filter:

```
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow flow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(requestChannel())
                    .transform(new MapToObjectTransformer(Campaign.class))
                    .filter(Campaign.class, 
                            c -> c.getId() > 10 ? true : false, //if id > 10 then it's valid
                            e -> e.discardChannel(validationError()))
                    .handle(new MyHandler())
                    .get();
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow validationErrorFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(validationError())
                    .handle(new ValidationHandler())//construct a message with the validation errors
                    .get();
        }
```

It works, but that way if I use a [spring validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) then i have to call it twice, in the filter and in the ValidationHandler (can be a transformer) to get the errors.

Any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.handle(new ValidationHandler())
```

You don't really need to create a new handler for each error.

In your filter, if the validation fails, throw `MyValidationException(errors)`.

In the error flow on the gateway's error channel, the `ErrorMessage` has a payload that is a `MessagingException` with the `MyValidatationException` as its cause, and the `failedMessage`.

Something like...

```
.handle(validationErrorHandler())

...

@Bean
public MessageHandler validationErrorHandler() {
    return new AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler() {
        public Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> error) {
            MyValidationException myEx = (MyValidationException) 
                  ((ErrorMessage) error).getPayload.getCause();
            Errors errors = myEx.getErrors();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use a POJO messageHandler

```
public Object handle(MessagingException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gary. One more thing: If the gateway is `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` is there a way to return `400 BadRequest`?

Comment: Found it: The GW resolves the http status by the `http_statusCode` header. So: in the handler  `return MessageBuilder.withPayload("some error")
               .setHeader("http_statusCode", "400")
               .build();`